# How to convert multiple .doc files to .docx using antiword?

Tags: python, bash, .doc

This manual command is working:

```
!antiword "test" > "test.docx"
```

but the following script convert files to empty .docx files:

```
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    subprocess.run(["bash", "-c", "antiword \"$1\" > \"$1\".docx", "_", file])
```

also it stores the .docx file in the previous directly e-g file is in \a\b this command will store the files to \a

I have tried many different ways including running directly on terminal adn bash loops. ony the manual way works.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work (adjust `dest_path` etc. accordingly).

```
import os
import shlex

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if ".doc" not in filename:
        continue
    path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    dest_path = os.path.splitext(path)[0] + ".txt"
    cmd = "antiword %s > %s" % (shlex.quote(path), shlex.quote(dest_path))
    print(cmd)
    # If the above seems to print correct commands, add:
    # os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: I dd, of course, but all I am getting is empty txt files - I don't understand what am I doing wrong. Thank you anyway, I converted the files using UIpath as my last resort as I am on the clock.